# Flutter - Remove String after certain character?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way to remove all characters after specific character in the String object in Flutter?

Suppose that I have the following string:

> one.two

and I need to remove the ".two" from it. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: is the purpose of this to remove an extension from a file name?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the `subString` method from the `String` class

```
String s = "one.two";

//Removes everything after first '.'
String result = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'));
print(result);
```

In case there are more than one '.' in the `String` it will use the first occurrance. If you need to use the last one (to get rid of a file extension, for example) change `indexOf` to `lastIndexOf`. If you are unsure there is at least one occurrance, you should also add some validation to avoid triggering an exception.

```
String s = "one.two.three";

//Remove everything after last '.'
var pos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
String result = (pos != -1)? s.substring(0, pos): s;
print(result);
```

Comment: To keep it even simpeler, with 's' as the initial string `one.two`
then 
`s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'))` produces: `one` and
`s.substring(s.indexOf('.') + 1)` produces: `two`

Comment: if you want to remove only one. and keep the two. How it can be done?

Comment: @Carlos Do you know how to remove everything BEFORE the '.'? If its possible may you please include it in your answer?

Answer (score 15):

```
void main() {
  String str = "one.two";
  print(str.replaceAll(".two", ""));

  // or

  print(str.split(".").first);

  // or

  String newStr = str.replaceRange(str.indexOf("."), str.length, "");
  print(newStr);


  // Lets do a another example

  String nums = "1,one.2,two.3,three.4,four";
  List values = nums.split("."); // split() will split from . and gives new List with separated elements.
  values.forEach(print);

  //output

//   1,one
//   2,two
//   3,three
//   4,four
}
```

Edit this in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/85b942a46e922bb50d05fbc0134c0c6e).

Actually, there are other cool methods in `String`. Check those [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/String-class.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
String str = "one.two";
var value = str?.replaceFirst(RegExp(r"\.[^]*"), "");
```

You can use `str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.'));` if you sure `str` contains `.`

Otherwise you will get error `Value not in range: -1`.

Comment: You can use `[^]` to match all characters, rather than `(.|\s)` or `[\s\S]` or other workarounds. Then the regexp could be just `r"\.[^]*"`.

Comment: @Irn ohh... Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is above but here is how you can do it if you want **only certain character position** or location.

To get substring from a Dart String, we use `substring()` method:

```
String str = 'bezkoder.com';

// For example, here we want ‘r’ is the ending. In ‘bezkoder.com’,
// the index of ‘r’ is 7. So we need to set endIndex by 8.
str.substring(0,8); // bezkoder

str.substring(2,8); // zkoder
str.substring(3);   // koder.com
```

This is the signature of `substring()` method that returns a String:

```
String substring(int startIndex, [int endIndex]);
```

`startIndex`: index of character to start with. Beginning index is 0.
`endIndex` (optional): index of ending character + 1. If it is not set, the result will be a subtring starting from startIndex to the end of the string.

[Reference]
[1]: https://bezkoder.com/dart-string-methods-operators-examples/

Comment: `name.substring(0, 30)` did the magic

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "one.two";
  print(str.replaceAll(".two", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working code that combines all above solutions

Maybe my syntax writing and splitting code is not common,, sorry for that I'm self taught beginner

```
// === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

/// in case you are saving assets in flutter project folder directory like this
/// 'assets/xyz/somFolder/image.jpg'
/// And u have a separate class where u save assets in variables like this to easily call them in your widget tree
/// 
/// class SuperDuperAsset {
///   static const String DumAuthorPic = 'assets/dum/dum_author_pic.jpg' ;
///   static const String DumBusinessLogo = 'assets/dum/dum_business_logo.jpg' ;
///   }
///   
/// I just want to insert SuperDuperAsset.DumBusinessLogo in this function below
/// 
/// and here is a fix and a combination for all mentioned solutions that works like a charm in case you would like to copy paste it
/// and just use this function like this
/// 
/// File _imageFile = await getImageFileFromAssets(SuperDuperAsset.DumBusinessLogo);
/// and you are good to go
/// 
/// some other functions that manipulate the asset path are separated below
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String asset) async {
  
  String _pathTrimmed = removeNumberOfCharacterFromAString(asset, 7);
  
  final _byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$_pathTrimmed');
  
  final _tempFile = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${getFileNameFromAsset(_pathTrimmed)}');
  
  await _tempFile.writeAsBytes(_byteData.buffer.asUint8List(_byteData.offsetInBytes, _byteData.lengthInBytes));
  
  _tempFile.create(recursive: true);
  
  return _tempFile;

}
// === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
String removeNumberOfCharacterFromAString(String string, int numberOfCharacters){
  String _stringTrimmed;
  if (numberOfCharacters > string.length){
    print('can not remove ($numberOfCharacters) from the given string because : numberOfCharacters > string.length');
    throw('can not remove ($numberOfCharacters) from the given string because');
  } else {
    _stringTrimmed = string.length >0 ? string?.substring(numberOfCharacters) : null;
  }
  return _stringTrimmed;
}
// === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
/// this trims paths like
/// 'assets/dum/dum_business_logo.jpg' to 'dum_business_logo.jpg'
String getFileNameFromAsset(String asset){
  String _fileName = trimTextBeforeLastSpecialCharacter(asset, '/');
  return _fileName;
}
// === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
String trimTextBeforeLastSpecialCharacter(String verse, String specialCharacter){
  int _position = verse.lastIndexOf(specialCharacter);
  String _result = (_position != -1)? verse.substring(_position+1, verse.length): verse;
  return _result;
}
// === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = RegExp(r'.[a-z]*$');
String s='one.two';
print(s.replaceAll(regex,''));
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?